# unresolved reference: override (onCreate)

Tags: kotlin

why is there an **unresolved reference** on override at the `onCreate` method? (**Kotlin**)

```
// unresolved reference: override
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // MapFragment erstellen und anzeigen
    startMapFragment()
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    // OnClickListener für SpeicherDetailActivity
    btnDetailSpeichern.setOnClickListener {
        val detailIntent = Intent(this, SpeicherDetailActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(detailIntent)
    }
}
```

I tried to clean and rebuild the Project.
I deleted the onCreate method and let AndroidStudio generate an new one (by pressing CTRL + O).
I copied an onCreate method from another Activitiy,
but nothing of this worked.

Here is the full Activity:

```
class SpeicherActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnMapReadyCallback {

// Variablem für MapFragment erstellen
var mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance()
var fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
var muennerstand : Ort = Ort(20.0, 5.0, "Münnerstadt", "", 0.0f)
var standartMarker = MarkerOptions().position(LatLng(muennerstand.latitute, muennerstand.longitute)).title("standart")

// GPS TEST
val locManager = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER.


// unresolved reference: override
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    // MapFragment erstellen und anzeigen
    startMapFragment()
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    // OnClickListener für SpeicherDetailActivity
    btnDetailSpeichern.setOnClickListener {
        val detailIntent = Intent(this, SpeicherDetailActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(detailIntent)
    }
}



// MapFragment erstellen und anzeigen
fun startMapFragment() {
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragmentContainer, mapFragment)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}

override fun onMapReady(mMap : GoogleMap?) {
   mMap?.addMarker(standartMarker)
 }
}
```

Comment: Some additional details that will help us solve this issue: 1) Are there other Kotlin activities in your project that don't have this issue? 2) Have you recently migrated from using Java in your project to using Kotlin? 3) Please post your Gradle build and application config files for us to see - specifically the Kotlin build setup.

Comment: I did not use Java before in this project i started it with Kotlin.
Only this class has this issue, other classes work perfect. This class was too working finde, until i added some permissions to the manifest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code. Remove the full-stop at the end of the "locManager" variable declaration line. That should fix your issue.

```
// GPS TEST
val locManager = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER
```

Comment: No worries @G.Lukas ! I realised it had to be a syntax error when you said that you've been working with Kotlin all along and this was the only class with the issue :P That full-stop was difficult to see and wasn't specifically highlighted in Android Studio as the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="de.gehring.lukas.spots">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MenuActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SpeicherActivity" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyC0UexE7q6vmBsohyJPkIwRbp1V75em9o4" />

    <activity
        android:name=".SpeicherDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_speicher_detail"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```